# Not receiving Resource ID from PHP MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, json

I tried echoing the value $query from a mysql_query request, but I am not receiving the resource #id that I usually receive. Please could you tell me what the problem is with the following code. Also, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how I could firstly get a for loop going to get the data from the query and secondly json encode it.

I would like the data from the query to be parsed as json like this:

Array of dictionaries, dictionary looking like this:

```
click_id = ....
shorten_url = ....
referrer = ....
ip_address = ....
country_code = ....
```

PHP:

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
mysql_select_db("nucleusi_mkdev") or die("Unable to select db");
$query = "SELECT  `click_id` ,  `shorturl` ,  `referrer` ,  `ip_address` ,  `country_code`FROM yourls_log";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo $result;
    ?>
```

Comment: What happens if you do var_dump($result) instead of echo? Is it just null?

Comment: it returns: resource(2) of type (mysql result). I tried mysql_num_rows, and that returned the correct amount of rows for the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource id could change per request. So I wouldn't focus on that. If you're curious about the results you can do `mysql_num_rows($result);`

The docs have great code samples. Check out [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) for looping over your query results and [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) for encoding each record.

A quick snippet to demo the two together:

```
$records = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
    array_push($records, $row);
}

echo json_encode($records);
```

Comment: how would I store the mysql_fetch_assoc() results, before they are json_encoded? Please be aware I am a newbie!

Comment: Did you try the code above. Check it out as it may give you some ideas. Elaborate on *store*.

Comment: works perfectly. I had to remove the print row, but it works :)